# Is there a numpy/scipy dot product, calculating only the diagonal entries of the result?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, product

Imagine having 2 numpy arrays:

```
> A, A.shape = (n,p)
> B, B.shape = (p,p)
```

Typically p is a smaller number (p <= 200), while n can be arbitrarily large.

I am doing the following:

```
result = np.diag(A.dot(B).dot(A.T))
```

As you can see, I am keeping only the n diagonal entries, however there is an intermediate (n x n) array calculated from which only the diagonal entries are kept.

I wish for a function like diag_dot(), which only calculates the diagonal entries of the result and does not allocate the complete memory.

A result would be:

```
> result = diag_dot(A.dot(B), A.T)
```

Is there a premade functionality like this and can this be done efficiently without the need for allocating the intermediate (n x n) array?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I think i got it on my own, but nevertheless will share the solution:

since getting only the diagonals of a matrix multiplication

```
> Z = N.diag(X.dot(Y))
```

is equivalent to the individual sum of the scalar product of rows of X and columns of Y, the previous statement is equivalent to:

```
> Z = (X * Y.T).sum(-1)
```

For the original variables this means:

```
> result = (A.dot(B) * A).sum(-1)
```

Please correct me if I am wrong but this should be it ...

Comment: +1 Smart algebra is always better than sophisticated algorithms.

Comment: In case someone is new to numpy, the emphasis here is on the difference between the X.dot(Y) operator and the * operator.
X.dot(Y) represents the conventional matrix product from Linear Algebra, whereas, X * Y returns the point wise product between the entries of X and Y, hence X and Y need to have the same shape.

Comment: Although I like your answer, I think it calculates all elements. The point of this question is to make the compiler understand that we are only interested in the diagonal elements :)

Answer (score 42):

You can get almost anything you ever dreamed of with [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html). Until you start getting the hang of it, it basically seems like black voodoo...

```
>>> a = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
>>> b = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)

>>> np.diag(np.dot(np.dot(a, b), a.T))
array([  60,  672, 1932, 3840, 6396])
>>> np.einsum('ij,ji->i', np.dot(a, b), a.T)
array([  60,  672, 1932, 3840, 6396])
>>> np.einsum('ij,ij->i', np.dot(a, b), a)
array([  60,  672, 1932, 3840, 6396])
```

**EDIT** You can actually get the whole thing in a single shot, it's ridiculous...

```
>>> np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->i', a, b, a.T)
array([  60,  672, 1932, 3840, 6396])
>>> np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', a, b, a)
array([  60,  672, 1932, 3840, 6396])
```

**EDIT** You don't want to let it figure too much on its own though... Added the OP's answer to its own question for comparison also.

```
n, p = 10000, 200
a = np.random.rand(n, p)
b = np.random.rand(p, p)

In [2]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->i', a, b, a.T)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.3 s per loop

In [3]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,ij->i', np.dot(a, b), a)
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit np.diag(np.dot(np.dot(a, b), a.T))
1 loops, best of 3: 5.73 s per loop

In [5]: %timeit (a.dot(b) * a).sum(-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop
```

Comment: I have not known this function - but certainly will do so now. Thx for sharing!!!

Comment: I believe’In [3]’ relies on the fact that ‘dot’ is highly optimized c code (blas?) However this does construct a potentially large intermediate array.

Comment: I'm not sure what np.einsum('ij,ij->i', np.dot(a, b), a) gives but it certainly a different result than that of Z = N.diag(X.dot(Y)) which delivers the diagonal elements of the dot product (In this case [ 15,  54, 111]).

Comment: Since 2013 there have been changes.  `einsum` performance can be improved with the `optimize=True` option.  There is a new batch oriented `matmul` that can solve this with: `(A[:,None,:]@B@A[:,:,None])[:,0,0]`.  But `(A.dot(B) * A).sum(-1)` remains a good method.

Comment: 10 years old but love it...

Answer (score 2):

A pedestrian answer, which avoids the construction of large intermediate arrays is:

```
result=np.empty([n,], dtype=A.dtype )
for i in xrange(n):
    result[i]=A[i,:].dot(B).dot(A[i,:])
```

Comment: `[n.]` is not valid Python. Did you mean `A.shape`?

Comment: @wkschwartz fixed.  No, just pre-allocating the result array.