# Efficient way to vectorize matrix calculus in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

In my current project, I wish to vectorize the calculation of the exponent of a multivariate normal Gaussian exponent:

f(X) = exp( - x.T * cov * x)

This is easy to implement in Python if `x` is just a D-dimensional vector. In my project, however, I wish to repeat this operation N times. Consequently, `x` is not a D-vector but a N-by-D matrix.

I know of two ways to calculate this:

1. Case I: Create a for loop and solve the matrix operations one at a time
2. Case II: Implement this as a (vectorized) single operation using the N-by-D matrix instead of the D-vector.

The second approach is actually faster for moderate N, but computes a lot of unnecessary information: it returns a full N-by-N matrix, but the results we seek are only the ones along its diagonal.

Is there a way to simplify the vectorized calculations (case II), computing and returning only the diagonal terms?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats
import time

# Number of samples
N       = 1000

# Draw samples
X       = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(size = (N,2))

# Define a covariance matrix
cov     = np.asarray([[4.,3.],[3.,9.]])

# Case I: Solve this with a for loop
start   = time.time()
z       = np.zeros(N)
for n in range(N):
    x       = X[n,:]
    z[n]    = np.exp(-np.linalg.multi_dot((
        x[np.newaxis,:],
        np.linalg.inv(cov),
        x[:,np.newaxis]))[0,0])
print('For loop operation took '+str(time.time()-start)+' seconds.')
# For loop operation took 0.017468929290771484 seconds.

# Case II: A single, vectorized calculation with unnecessary operations
start   = time.time()
z2      = np.exp(-np.linalg.multi_dot((X,np.linalg.inv(cov),X.T)))

# We only need the diagonal of this
z2      = np.diag(z2)
print('Vectorized operation took '+str(time.time()-start)+' seconds.')
# Vectorized operation took 0.011204957962036133 seconds.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a numpy/scipy dot product, calculating only the diagonal entries of the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758283/is-there-a-numpy-scipy-dot-product-calculating-only-the-diagonal-entries-of-the)