# Is there a numpy/scipy dot product for sparse matrix, calculating only the diagonal entries of the result?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

Imagine having 2 sparse matrix:

```
> A, A.shape = (n,m)
> B, B.shape = (m,n)
```

I would like to compute the dot product `A*B`, but then only keep the diagonal. The matrices being big, I actually don't want to compute other values than the ones in the diagonal.

This is a variant of the question [Is there a numpy/scipy dot product, calculating only the diagonal entries of the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758283/is-there-a-numpy-scipy-dot-product-calculating-only-the-diagonal-entries-of-the)

Where the most relevant answer seems to be to use `np.einsum`:

```
np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A, B)
```

However this does not work:

```
ValueError: einstein sum subscripts string contains too many subscripts for operand 0
```

The solution is to use `todense()`, but it increases a lot the memory usage: `np.einsum('ij,ji->i', A.todense(), B.todense())`

The other solution, that I currently use, is to iterate over all the rows of A and compute each product in the loop :

```
for i in range(len_A):
   result = np.float32(A[i].dot(B[:, i])[0, 0])
   ...
```

None of these solutions seems perfect. Is there an equivalent to `np.einsum` that could work with sparse matrices ?

Comment: can you give a small numerical example of what you expect?

Comment: Please include a [mre]. It's mich easier to see if a solution is correct.

Comment: In general, is `n` ≠ `p`?

Comment: no, I've corrected it: n = p

Comment: Unless `A` and `B` are excessively large, the `einsum` with `A.A` and `B.A` might still be faster.   Taking the diagonal of `A@B` might not be a bad option either.  For sparse matrices, matrix multiplication is faster than element-wise.

Comment: For a small test case, batched `@` is fastest, `(A.A[:,None,:] @ (B.A.T)[:,:,None]).squeeze()`.  Your iterative solution shows that this is really a set of 1d inner products.

Answer (score 2):

```
[sum(A[i]*B.T[i]) for i in range(min(A.shape[0], B.shape[1]))]
```

otherwise this is faster:

```
l = min(A.shape[0], B.shape[1])
(A[np.arange(l)]*B.T[np.arange(l)]).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general you shouldn't try to use numpy functions on the `scipy.sparse` arrays. In your case I'd first make sure both arrays actually have a compatible shape, that is

```
A, A.shape = (r,m)
B, B.shape = (m,r)
```

where `r = min(n, p)`. Then we can compute the diagonal of the matrix product using

```
d = (A.multiply(B.T)).sum(axis=1)
```

Here we compute the entry wise row-column products, and manually sum them up. This avoids all the unnecessary computations you'd get using `dot`/`@`/`*`. (Note that unlike in numpy, both `*` and `@` perform matrix multiplication.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks, I mixed it up - I updated my answer.