# Using vectorization to get rid of for cycle in matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

We have two matrices A and B, where

```
A.shape # Output T,N
B.shape # Output N,N,T
```

and we are interested in calculating the mult value, which I am calculating using for cycle right now

```
mult=0
for t in range(0,T):
    mult +=   np.matmul(np.matmul(A[t,:].T , B[:,:,t]) ,A[t,:])
```

I have already found a similar problem, which I am confident can be helpful in find the solution [Is there a numpy/scipy dot product, calculating only the diagonal entries of the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758283/is-there-a-numpy-scipy-dot-product-calculating-only-the-diagonal-entries-of-the), but I am unable to come up with a clean solution without using the for cycle.

Is there a way of using only basic numpy operations to get the desired result?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can get away with a call to [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```py
mult = np.einsum('ij, jki, ik ->', A, B, A)
```

What this does is compute the summation

```
sum_{i, j, k} A[i, j] * B[j, k, i] * A[i, k]
```

which is what you need.

Note that in your original code `A[t, :].T` is a 1d array, so transposition is a no-op, this is just `A[t, :]`.

Also note that `np.einsum` might be concise, but it's often slower than the corresponding calls to `np.dot` or elementwise operations. So you might get other answers that end up being faster. I haven't timed this approach.

---

Case in point: there's a direct multiplication alternative making use of array broadcasting:

```py
mult = (A[:, None, :] * B.T * A[..., None]).sum()
```

Now, there's a lot of legroom here: we could choose to transpose `A` instead, or only reorder some of the indices of `B` and so on. The corresponding performance will depend on your use case, because memory access ends up being highly non-trivial (which impacts caching, which is mostly where vectorisation speedup comes from).

For example, for `T = 10` and `N = 100` and uniform random matrices we get these timings:

```
>>> %timeit loopy(A, B)
... %timeit einsummed(A, B)
... %timeit mulled(A, B)

179 µs ± 591 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
304 µs ± 1.33 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
309 µs ± 2.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

(`loopy()` is your code, `einsummed()` is my first solution and `mulled()` is my second.) So both einsum and the direct summation end up being almost twice as slow. This is because your loop goes over a "small" index of size 10, where looping often outperforms vectorised solutions.

In contrast, if we choose `T = 100` and `N = 10` we get

```
>>> %timeit loopy(A, B)
... %timeit einsummed(A, B)
... %timeit mulled(A, B)
231 µs ± 1.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
37.9 µs ± 265 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
38.1 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Now my two approaches are almost six times faster.

Whether either of these is faster than your loop depends on your real problem. Time them and see.

Comment: @hamamuta I ended up adding a direct multiplication approach and some timings. My main point is that profiling different approaches for your real data (or something similar) is crucial to figure out which one is best :)