# Broadcasting for numpy array - vectorized quadratic form

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to compute the part of multivariate normal distribution density that is a quadratic form

```
(X - mu)^T * S * (X - mu)
```

Assume the data

```
mu = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
S = np.array([np.eye(3)*3, np.eye(3)*5])
X = np.array([np.random.random(3*10)]).reshape(10, 3)
```

Now, an iterative process would be to calculate

```
(X[0] - mu[0]) @ S[0] @ (X[0] - mu[0]).T, (X[0] - mu[1]) @ S[1] @ (X[0] - mu[1]).T
```

(I don't need to vectorize with respect to `X`). However, I guess that's not the fastest approach. What I tried is

```
np.squeeze((X[0] - mu)[:, None] @ S) @ ((X[0] - mu)).T
```

But the values that I want are placed on the main diagonal of matrix above. I could use `np.diagonal()`, but is there a better way to perform the calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were almost there. You have matrix `A = np.squeeze((X[0] - mu)[:, None] @ S)` which you matrix multiply with `B = ((X[0] - mu)).T)` but you only want the diagonal elements.

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758283/is-there-a-numpy-scipy-dot-product-calculating-only-the-diagonal-entries-of-the) `C = N.diag(A.dot(B))` is equivalent to `C = (A * B.T).sum(-1)` which leads to the following solution:

```
import numpy as np

mu = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
S = np.array([np.eye(3)*3, np.eye(3)*5])
X = np.array([np.random.random(3*10)]).reshape(10, 3)

res1 = (X[0] - mu[0]) @ S[0] @ (X[0] - mu[0]).T, (X[0] - mu[1]) @ S[1] @ (X[0] - mu[1]).T

res2 = (np.squeeze((X[0] - mu)[:, None] @ S) * (X[0] - mu)).sum(-1)
print(res1)
print(res2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be expressed using [np.einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) allowing you to broadcast over X as well:

```
import numpy as np
mu = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
S = np.array([np.eye(3)*3, np.eye(3)*5])
X = np.random.random((10, 3))

resOP = np.array([(X[0] - mu[0]) @ S[0] @ (X[0] - mu[0]).T, (X[0] - mu[1]) @ S[1] @ (X[0] - mu[1]).T])
resNin17 = np.einsum("...ij, ...ij->...i", np.einsum("...j, ...ij", (X[:, None] - mu), S), (X[:, None] - mu))

assert np.allclose(resOP, resNin17[0])
```

Or to just calculate one row:

```
assert np.array_equal(resNin17[2], np.einsum("...ij, ...ij->...i", np.einsum("...j, ...ij", (X[2] - mu), S), (X[2] - mu)))
```